# Docker daemon error after updating docker

Tags: docker

I updated docker on my system. After this when I run docker commands I get the error "Cannot contact docker daemon".

Running `systemctl status docker` shows me that the docker daemon failed to start.
Inspecting the systemd journal with `journalctl -xe` shows me the following error :

```
ERROR: ZONE_CONFLICT: 'docker0' already bound to a zone
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as root:

```bash
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Source : https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#integration-with-firewalld

> If you are running Docker version 20.10.0 or higher with firewalld on your system with `--iptables` enabled, Docker automatically creates a `firewalld` zone called `docker` and inserts all the network interfaces it creates (for example, `docker0`) into the docker zone to allow seamless networking.
>
> Consider running the following `firewalld` command to remove the docker interface from the zone.
>
> Please substitute the appropriate zone and docker interface
>
> ```
> firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0 --permanent
> firewall-cmd --reload
> ```
>
> Restarting dockerd daemon inserts the interface into the docker zone.